# What is the name of this component in logic board?

Tags: circuit-design

[image: electronic component]

This picture is for my tablet logic board, there are two of this component on the board, one is kinda rusty so I removed it and wanted to replace it but then I don't know the name of it. Can anyone can? thanks in advance

Comment: A cylindrical quartz crystal? Are there any markings on it?

Comment: Yes, should be crystal oscillator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oscillator. Its frequency should be marked on the body. I think this kind devices are up to 1 MHz (I was dealing with value of 32768 Hz)

Comment: @KenShirriff thank you for answering,.. i don't see any markings on it , how can i know the value ?

Comment: i found it ,, it takes me 2mins to notice the small engraved 32. 768 mark on it ... thank you guys .. thank you @KenShirriff

Answer (score 1):

It's a crystal, part of an oscillator on that board.

Such cylinder crystals used to be commonplace in the through-hole days of the 1970's and 1980's. They gave way to rectangular packages that were easier to solder or anchor to PCBs, reducing failure through vibration and shock. They then gave way to much smaller surface-mount packages that were anchored at both ends, improving resilience much further. These old cylinder crystals are still around but much less so.

Comment: Not to mention that you'd want SMD today, for automated placement and reflow soldering.

Comment: Glaring omission in my answer, now revised - thanks very much @pipe :-)

Comment: The majority of 32 kHz crystals use in compute appliances today are still the old cylindrical style or the long metal can type. The SMD's are very expensive (2 * the price) since providing the support structure for the crystal/fork in the package is a real challenge. The size of the crystal/fork at these low frequencies sets the form factor size ....and the crystal is a long bar or tuning fork.

Comment: Thank you for answering guys :) its my first time here :D really appreciated:) thank you :)